# Can "scary" also mean "scared"?

Tags: word-difference

The [Merriam Webster online dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scary) says that "scary" means either "causing fright" or "feeling fright”.

> **scary**
>   1 : causing fright : ALARMING
>   *a scary story*
>   2 : easily scared : TIMID
>   3 : feeling alarm or fright : FRIGHTENED

Is it possible to use "scary" when you mean "scared"?

Comment: Can you please edit your question to add an example sentence, showing how you’d use _scary_ to mean _scared_? Asking “Is it possible...” is a bit open-ended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the examples on Merriam-Webster; they have one for ***scary*** meaning *frightened* that matches my own experience.

I actually came to this all ready to explain how it's a rare usage, and I still think it is, but M-W are all on top of that.

However, I disagree with their actual definition for that usage. But let's look at it:

> a **scary** horse who spooked and kicked at its own shadow

When a horse is prone to getting frightened, either in general or as a temporary mood, we use words that sound like they mean something else in other contexts. To indicate that it's easily scared, we say it's ***scary***; to indicate that it's easily spooked (almost the same thing), we say it's ***spooky***. The horse community has a lot of words that are recognisably unique to that domain, but they also have plenty of words that have subtly (or not-so-subtly) different meanings from their general use.

For instance, both the verb *to spook* and the verb *to scare* can take both their usual meaning with respect to horses, and a slightly alternate meaning. If a horse ***spooks***, it means a fairly specific set of behaviour and movement, where it stops and jerks backwards and/or sideways, maybe rearing a bit. If *you* spook a horse, then properly, you've caused it to spook. It's a little less common (possibly a little archaic), but the same applies to a horse ***scaring***. When a horse *scares*, it is frightened, but more specifically it might spook a bit (or it might not), and then it runs off with disregard for instructions from a human - even a human on its back. Assuming the human on its back has managed to *stay* on its back.

Thus, a horse that *is spooky* is prone to spooking or close to spooking, and a horse that *is scary* is prone to scaring or close to scaring. For a horse to be close to scaring, it's probably already a little out of its wits with fear (or sometimes other causes - drugs, agitation, irritation by insects, etc.).

That sense of *scare* seems to have been overtaken in recent decades by the similar (but not identical) term ***bolt***. However, I've never heard of a horse being *bolty*. The *scare* usage turns up in phrases that are slightly more current, like "horse scare", referring to an event where one or more horses scared and it became somehow notable. I suspect it's also the origin of such uses as "he doesn't scare easy", meaning that it is not easy to frighten him; I believe that expression was originally specifically used for horses (and other animals), got ported across to humans, and lost its distinct meaning of *scary*. Similarly, the saying "don't scare the horses" most likely didn't mean "don't make the horses frightened", but "don't cause the horses to run away in shock/agitation". Now it is used metaphorically.

Answer (score -1):

No, they are not equivalent. A person is ***scared*** of something that is ***scary***. Being "scared" means feeling afraid. Something being "scary" means that is causes people to feel afraid.

Comment: That’s what I usually think, too – but that seems to contradict definition 3 in M-W, which is why I think the OP is asking this question. [Other dictionaries](https://www.wordnik.com/words/scary) seem to support this definition, also.

Comment: I've never heard it used that way (definition 3), but I'm from the US. So maybe it's something that's common in the UK or elsewhere? Or perhaps an antiquated usage that's not used much anymore?

Comment: @JT - Those are good points/questions that should probably be addressed in your answer.

Comment: Collins shows that usage as British https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/scary

Comment: As J. Taylor says, I've never heard it used that way either - (and I've been around a while - UK, America, Africa and Australia ).

Comment: It's kinda specific to horses (and possibly similar animals)...

Comment: Very interesting SamBC. I don't have any experience with horses, and hadn't heard of this. Thanks for sharing.